# How to append an array to a div?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm having some trouble getting my array to load into a specified area in my HTML, currently the HTML looks like this:

```
 <body>
    <div id="japan"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="Fisher-Yates.js"></script>
```

and my Javascript is:

```
let hiragana = [あ, い, う, え, お];
let result = shuffle(hiragana);
let div = document.getElementById('japan');


for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
     div.appendChild(result[i]);
}
```

It will appear in the body if I replace the div.appendChild with document.body.appendChild instead, so I think some of the code should work, I'm just not sure what I'm missing!

EDIT:   I should also mention that the array is variables that are images I'd like to load in at random, this is the rest of the code:

```
    function shuffle(array) {
      var m = array.length,
        t,
        i;
      while (m) {
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
      }
      return array;
    }

    let あ = document.createElement("img");
    あ.src = "/images/あ.png";
    //あ.setAttribute("width", "25%");

    let い = document.createElement("img");
    い.src = "/images/い.png";

    let う = document.createElement("img");
    う.src = "/images/う.png";

    let え = document.createElement("img");
    え.src = "/images/え.png";

    let お = document.createElement("img");
    お.src = "/images/お.png";
```

Comment: What is your shuffle function look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the image elements at the top of the code.

```js
let あ = document.createElement("img");
あ.src = "/images/あ.png";
//あ.setAttribute("width", "25%");

let い = document.createElement("img");
い.src = "/images/い.png";

let う = document.createElement("img");
う.src = "/images/う.png";

let え = document.createElement("img");
え.src = "/images/え.png";

let お = document.createElement("img");
お.src = "/images/お.png";

let hiragana = [あ, い, う, え, お];
let result = shuffle(hiragana);
let div = document.getElementById('japan');


for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  div.appendChild(result[i]);
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length,
    t,
    i;
  while (m) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="japan"></div>
</body>
<script src="Fisher-Yates.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I added the rest of my script to the original post, your method does get the array into the div, but I don't think inner HTML will work since the variables inside the array are images.

Comment: So was the issue the order of my original code?  Your update works!  I'm excited, but want to make sure I understand what I missed.

Comment: Yes, I think the order was the issue :)

Comment: I'm new to coding, it seems like a lot of the time it's something small like that and I always feel like a dope when I finally get it lol.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `div.appendChild(result[i]);` Have you tried below code:

```
 <body>
    <div id="japan"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="Fisher-Yates.js"></script>

let hiragana = [あ, い, う, え, お];
let result = shuffle(hiragana);
div = document.getElementById('japan');


for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + result[i];
}
```